# UIViewを継承したサブクラスにおけるコンストラクタについて。

Tags: swift

```
class Graphic: UIView {

    var _context: CGContextRef!
    var w: Float!
    var h: Float!
    var photo: Photo


override init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    w = Float(self.frame.width)
    h = Float(self.frame.height)
    photo.initialize(CGFloat(w), h: CGFloat(h))

}


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Photoは自作クラスで特に何も継承していません。
このとき、

```
super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
```

において、

```
Property self.photo not initialized at super init call
```

というエラーが表示されます。
また、photo の宣言がなかったとしてもfatalErrorになってしまいます。

ここで質問なのですが、まず、UIViewにおいてのコンストラクタのoverrideと、ある自作クラスを宣言した上でのUIViewにおけるその取り扱いを教えていただけないでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: あなたのコードをそのまま(閉じ`}`を補って)Xcode7.2.1のPlaygroundで試すと、ご記載のエラーが再現できません。エラーが発生した時のコードをそのまま掲示していただけるでしょうか。「fatalErrorになってしまいます」と言うのも何を表したいのかがよくわかりません。あなたの経験した「fatalError」について、もう少し詳しく記述してください。なお、UIViewに限らず、Swiftでのコンストラクタの記述については[Swift本(TSPL:The Swift Programming Language)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097)の[Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)中に詳しく記載されています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swiftでは、コンストラクタ（Constructor）と呼ばずに、イニシアライザ（**Initializer**）と呼びます。

[The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html)

Apple自身によるSwiftの解説文書では、いちどもConstructorという単語は出てきません。

---

`UIView`のサブクラスの実装のしかたですが、(1) *プロパティの宣言*、(2) *イニシアライザの実装*のふたつに分けて説明したいと思います。たがいに密接に関係していることですが、分けてみていったほうが、理解しやすくなるだろうと思います。

**プロパティの宣言**
クラスのプロパティは、その型の種類と、初期値の有無で、つぎのように分類できます。
(1) Optional型で宣言する。
ごぞんじのように、`nil`である可能性のある変数を、Optional型の変数といい、`var image: UIImage?`というように、型名に`?`を付して、Optional型であることを示します。宣言時、暗黙的に`nil`が代入されるので、`var image: UIImage? = nil`と同等です。Optional型のプロパティは、未設定という状態を示す必要があるケースで使われます。たとえば、`UIImageView`のプロパティ`image`がOptional型ですが、イメージのない空白の`UIImageView`のインスタンスの状態が、じっさいに存在するので、Optional型となっています。
(2) Implicitly unwrapped optional型で宣言する。
これもご存じのように`!`を型名に付して示します。例：`@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!`。この型の宣言は、特殊なケースを除いて推奨されません。そもそもImplicitly unwrapped optional型は、プログラマの責任において、まちがいなく`nil`にならないことが保証されるケース以外で、使うべきでないからです。プロパティにおける特殊なケースで有名なのは、XIB書類、Storyboardのオブジェクトに紐付けされたプロパティですが、XIB書類、Storyboardが、その存在を定義しているため（存在が保証されるため）だと考えられます。
(3) 非Optional型で、初期値を与える。
プロパティでなく、一般の変数の宣言においても、非Optional型の変数は、宣言時に初期値を与える必要があります。それとおなじです。例：`var x: Float = 0.0`。Optional型のプロパティ以外は、できるだけこの形で宣言すべきと、わたしは考えます。
(4) 非Optional型で、初期値を与えない宣言。
指定イニシアライザで、プロパティに値が代入されるケースに限って、非Optional型のプロパティでも、初期値をなしにできます。ご提示のコード`var photo: Photo`がそれにあたりますが、イニシアライザの中で、`Photo`インスタンスを生成して、代入していないため、

> Property self.photo not initialized at super init call

というエラーが起きているのだと考えられます。

**イニシアライザの実装**
クラスのイニシアライザ（Initializer）は、指定イニシアライザ（Designated Initializer）と、簡易イニシアライザ（Convenience Initializer）に分けられます。クラスはかならず指定イニシアライザでインスタンスを生成します。簡易イニシアライザは、それ自身ではインスタンス生成はできず、その中で指定イニシアライザを呼ぶことで、インスタンス生成を可能にしています。簡易イニシアライザは、頭に`convenience`を付します。`UIView`では、`init(frame frame: CGRect)`が指定イニシアライザです。なお、XIB書類、Storyboardから生成するときは、`init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`が呼ばれます。

**イニシアライザの実行**
イニシアライザは、ほかの一般的なメソッドと異なる面を持ちますが、実行するコードも特殊な書式になります。

```
let newView = UIView.init(frame: newRect)
```

このような書式ではなく、

```
let newView = UIView(frame: newRect)
```

このように、クラス名に直接かっこをつないだものになります。

---

以上から、ご提示のクラス`Graphic`の定義コードの、ひとつの改善案はこうなります。

```
class Graphic: UIView {

    var context: CGContextRef? // Appleのプライベート識別子とバッティングする危険があるので、語頭にアンダーバーを付けない。
    var w: Float = 0.0
    var h: Float = 0.0
    var photo: Photo

    override init(frame frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        w = Float(self.frame.width)
        h = Float(self.frame.height)
        photo = Photo(CGFloat(w), h: CGFloat(h))
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        w = Float(self.frame.width)
        h = Float(self.frame.height)
        photo = Photo(CGFloat(w), h: CGFloat(h))
    }

}
```

これはあくまでひとつのアイデアです。各プロパティの役割を知らない状態で、推測に基づいて考えたものであって、それ以上のものではありません。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。なるほど、色々と曖昧だった部分があきらかになりました。おかげさまで無事解決いたしました。

Answer (score 0):

気になったところを1点だけ回答します。

> Property self.photo not initialized at super init call

このエラーですが、サブクラスで定義したプロパティをすべて初期化する前に、スーパークラスのイニシャライザを呼び出しているのが原因です。

photo以外のプロパティはimplicitly unwrapped optionalになっているため、暗黙的にnilで初期化されていますが、photoは宣言だけで初期化されていないためエラーになります。

可能であれば、宣言と同時に初期化することをおすすめします。

以下のコードで、コンパイルが通るところまでは確認しました。
（Xcode 7.2.1で確認）

```
import UIKit

class Photo {
    func initialize(w:CGFloat, h: CGFloat) {
    }
}

class GraphicsView: UIView {

    var _context: CGContextRef!
    var w: Float!
    var h: Float!

    // 宣言と同時に初期化
    var photo = Photo()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        w = Float(self.frame.width)
        h = Float(self.frame.height)
        photo.initialize(CGFloat(w), h: CGFloat(h))
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。photoの要素にnilを残したのが原因だったのですね。今後気をつけます。

Comment: 何か誤解されているように思われます。『宣言だけされて初期化されてない状態』と『nilで初期化されている状態』は別物です。一度わかってしまえばそんなに難しい概念ではないので、一度よく調べてみてください。